# How to map values in a List<Integer> to elements in a List<String> using Stream Api with Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have the following task.

We have **two lists**: the first one `integerList` of type `Integer` and the second `stringList` of type `String`.

The goal is:

- For each value `n` from `integerList` select a string from `stringList` that starts with a **digit** and has a length `n`;
- If there are several required strings in the `stringList`, select the first one;
- If there's no required string, place `"Not found"` as an appropriate element.

*My code:*

```
public static List<String> foo(List<Integer> integerList, List<String> stringList) {
    return integerList.stream()
        .map(integer -> stringList.stream()
                .filter(...) // not sure what to use here
                .findFirst()
                .orElse("Not found"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm not sure what should I use in the `filter`.

*Input:*

```
integerList = [1, 3, 4]
stringList = ["1aa", "aaa", "1", "a"]
```

*Desired output:*

```
["1", "1aa", "Not Found"]
```

Comment: I probably do not know how to map inside of another stream. Not found was only once because  for 1 we have string 1 , for 3 we have 1aa. for 4 we do not have any string with size 4

Comment: if there are some string of particular length - then get first of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate from the list of strings a map `Map<Integer,String>`, which associates *string length* with the first string in a list having this length.

And then process the contents of the list of integers.

To filter only those strings that start with a *digit*, we can use the following regular expression `"^//d.*"`, which would match any string that has a *digit* as its *first character*, followed by zero or more characters.

```
List<Integer> integerList = List.of(1, 3, 4);
List<String> stringList = List.of("1aa", "aaa", "1", "a");
        
Map<Integer, String> strByLength = stringList.stream()
    .filter(str -> str.matches("^//d.*")) // string starts with a digit
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        String::length,        // key
        Function.identity(),   // value
        (left, right) -> left  // pick the first encountered value
    ));
    
List<String> result1 = integerList.stream()
    .map(i -> strByLength.getOrDefault(i, "Not Found"))
    .toList();
    
System.out.println(result1);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 1aa, Not Found]
```

It can also be done by creating a nested stream inside `map()` operation, i.e. in the way that tried to achieve it. For that, you need to use the following *predicate* inside the `filter()` applied before `findFirst()`:

```
.filter(str -> str.length() == integer)
```

***Note*** that such solution is **less performant** than the first one, which uses `Map`, because it requires to iterate over the list of string as many times as there are elements in the list of integers. Meanwhile, the map-based approach requires only a single iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Java Strings have a `length()` method you can use to check the number of characters.

For the first character check you can use the `charAt(index)` method also available in String.

You can combine this with the `Character.isDigit(char)` method to check for the requirement.

I guess a solution could look something like this

```
public static List<String> f(List<Integer> integerList, List<String> stringList) {
    return integerList.stream().map(
        integer -> stringList.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.length() == integer)
                .filter(s -> Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)))
                .findFirst().orElse("Not found")
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```